# Restful PHP web service Tutorial links?

Tags: php, web-services, mobile-application

I am new to PHP, can anybody tell me some good Tutorial links to Create Restfull PHP web services. I want to use it in iPhone app. I googled but could not find some healthy tutorial.

Can anybody send complete tutorial to develop Restful webservice in PHP from start to End.

Comment: Important to read about real REST web services: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: This question (in its current form) is a bad fit for the QA format. Voting to close it unless you can improve it. Also, you might look at this as a starting point for your problem - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/